# Trigger change of input value without user interaction in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two input fields, let's say #a and #b.

By clicking #a and inserting a char I fire an AJAX request.
The response is filling the value of #b.

How can I detect any changes here?

The code above only works by doing directly something in the browser

```
$('#b').on('change input keyup', function(){
  var that = $(this);
  console.log('changed');
  if(that.val()){
    console.log(that.val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not trigger the `change` event when *your code* changes the value of `#b` inside the success of your AJAX call ? `$('#b').trigger('change');`

Comment: You are meaning in/with the success procedure? Nope, because I've too update a lot of other fields

Comment: Select them all in your JQuery selector, then trigger the `change` event : `$('#b,#c,...').trigger('change');` or `$('#commonParent input').trigger('change');`

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. By trigger the change event in your way, this isn't working well. Sure he is jumping into the on('change.... event listener, but this is not solving my issue to jump into this listener after the value of #b has changed by the ajaxcall. or am I wrong?

Comment: Trigger them inside your AJAX call success !

Answer (score 1):

As listed on jquery docs [change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using
>   .val() for example, won't fire the event.

So you will need to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) your change event manually after your ajax success or convert the event to a function and just call it after ajax success.

Some developers went with [setinterval way](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/detect-change-of-hidden-input), but I think this is needed for special cases but just wanted to mention other options

Comment: hmmm I guess I got you. To use a intervall is bad from my point of view, because it is fired again and again and cost a lot of RAM. The best way is to fire my own privat event after the success ajax. thats it. thx

Comment: @user1357971 yes I agree with you, but also you can start it and end it when change is triggered.